# Weird padding being added to my webpage

Tags: html, css

Im building a webpage as part of an assignment, so fair warning, my css and html probably isnt very good.

Im having this issue where this invisble box appears to be pushing the text on my webpage to one side. not all the text, just the first couple lines. 
Here is an image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHjK6.jpg

For the life of me i am unable to find a reason for this.. weird margin.. to be added.
Here is my code:
http://pastebin.com/MVRpx8uq

Can anyone give me any insight as to why this is happening? Also if there is any way i could improve the code, pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: use your inspector in your browser

Comment: Do you mean the f12 developer view?

Comment: Remove `position: relative` from `#siteNavigation` and you're going to see what pushes some lines to the right

Comment: yes or get the web developer plugin and outline block level elements

Comment: You really should fix your broken markup! http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `clear: both;` to your "Locations" ID selector.

Instead of this:

```
#Locations
{
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Do this:

```
#Locations
{
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    text-align: left;
    clear: both;
}
```

Let me know if this works.